# Android picasso previously displays cached image

Tags: android, picasso

I have a problem with using Picasso to display list of images in a RecyclerView (Horizontal). I've followed this

```
Picasso.with(context)
            .load(worldObj.getCover())
            .fit()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
            .into(holder.mImageView));
```

but I still get the error "picasso previously displays cached image"

Any ideas why I'm getting this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    World worldObj = itemList.get(position);

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(worldObj.getCover())
            .fit()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)

            .into(holder.mImageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    // once the image is loaded, load the next image
                    Log.e("Success", "HELP");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Log.e("Error", "HELP");
            }
    });

}
```

Comment: What is that error ?

Comment: previously displays cached image

Comment: how and where are you using that snippet of code ?

Comment: @Blackbelt I'm using this in CustomAdapter

Comment: could you post the whole getView ?

Comment: Using .`memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)` you can prevent picasso  from caching the image.

Comment: @Blackbelt updated my post. pls. check thanks.

Comment: @AnoopM but it still displays the previous image

Comment: are you sure that `worldObj.getCover()` isn't returning over and over the same thing ?

Comment: Have you ever enabled cache before ?

Comment: @Blackbelt no, I'm not returning the same url

Comment: Well once you clear the application data/Uninstall and retry newly.

Comment: @AnoopM I tried but still the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(worldShowObj.getCover())
                .fit()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .into(holder.mImageView));
```

Instead **skipMemoryCache()**, try using this **memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)** that works for me.

Comment: `skipMemoryCache()` is deprecated.

Comment: what's `getShowCover()`

Comment: is just spell mistake, I have corrected it and ya it is deprecated method which I can use it for my further process.

Comment: have you copied the whole answer as it was posted by me?